# Why is $c_{n}$ a digit where $c_{n} = [10^{n}(x-c_{0})-10^{n-1}c_{1} - 10^{n-2}c_{2} - \cdots -10c_{n-1}]$ for $n = 1,2,3, \dots$?

Tags: real-analysis

For the problem

> Let $[x]$ denote the integer part of $x$; that is, $[x]$ is the integer satisfying $x-1 < [x] \leq x.$ Set $c_{0} = [x]$, and $c_{n} = [10^{n}(x-c_{0})-10^{n-1}c_{1} - 10^{n-2}c_{2} - \cdots -10c_{n-1}]$ for $n = 1,2,3, \dots$. Verify that the decimal representation of $x$ is $x = c_{0} + 0.c_{1}c_{2}c_{3} \cdots$

The following explanation is given

> Set $x_{n} = c_{0} + \frac{c_{1}}{10} + \cdots + \frac{c_{n}}{10^{n-1}}$. We have from the definition of $c_{n}$

> (1) $10^{n}(x-x_{n}) - 1 < c_{n} \leq 10^{n}(x-x_{n}).$

> First we establish that $c_{n}$ is a digit for $n \geq 1.$ We set $\epsilon_{0} = x - c_{0}$ and $\epsilon_{k} = 10^{k}(x-x_{k}) - c_{k}$ for $k \geq 1.$ From (1) we conclude that $0 \leq \epsilon_{k} < 1.$ Entering this result in (1) for $k = n-1$, we obtain $-1 \leq 10\epsilon_{n-1}-1 < c_{n} \leq 10\epsilon_{n-1} <10$. Since $c_{n}$ is an integer and $-1 < c_{n} <10$, it follows that $c_{n}$ must be one of the digits $0,1,2, \dots , 9$.

I'm having difficulty understanding why $c_{n}$ is a digit using the information provided. Does this follow from the fact that $0 \leq \epsilon_{k} < 1$?

Comment: Do you understand why $-1\leq 10\epsilon_{n-1}<c_n\leq 10\epsilon_{n-1}<10$? If so, the fact that $c_n$ is an integer and $-1<c_n<10$ directly gives the result.

Comment: Yes, I understand why $-1 \leq 10\epsilon_{n-1}-1 < c_{n} \leq 10\epsilon_{n-1} <10$. But what makes $c_{n}$ an integer? I thought that's what we were trying to prove?

Comment: $c_n$ is a sum/difference of integers (by, say, induction) and is thus itself an integer.